# Upgrade linux 14.04 to 18.04 and OpenVPN

Tags: openvpn

Until recently, our server OpenVPN was working with client versions 2.3.18. However, on newer versions (2.4.6) the client says "md certificates too weak."
We decided to update our server OpenVPN.
It was planned to update the system first and after OpenVPN.
Updated the system from 14 to 16 by means of the commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install update-manager-cоrе
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

For the first time the update went smoothly. Continued to upgrade to 18 versions. During the upgrade, the console hung and I was disconnected from it. The server is no longer available.

When the server was upgraded to version 16, it worked on the client 2.3.18. On a newer no.

In the report, I had to restore from the snapshot where there was a 14 version.

Tell me how to properly update our system.

Comment: Continued? ... Did you reboot after upgrading from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS? or just try and repeat the upgrade steps without the required reboot?

Comment: After these commands the server will require a reboot. 
The first time it took and I did it.
When upgrading to version 18, a crash occurred and everything broke.
Then I started again from the recovery point on version 14. Then when upgrading to 16 everything broke.